# My PadRight() isn't working - Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to retrieve my record from the database Microsoft SQL and write it into a .txt file. My code were working properly but PadRight() are not.

My question is : Why does my PadRight() isn't working?
*Even if I put the PadRight() in other column name it is still not working.

Output : If i put row("ProcessDate".PadRight(9)) it should only show the 6character value not the whole value.

For example: if the value of a ProcessDate from the database Microsoft SQL is 
11/8/2016 31342
The OUTPUT SHOULD BE : 11/8/2016

My Code:

```
 For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    swMonetary.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}",
        row("ProcessDate".PadRight(6)), 
        row("SubscriberAccountNumber"), 
        row("PayorName"), 
        row("ParNumber"), 
        row("MemberType"), 
        row("ApplicablePeriodStart"), 
        row("ApplicablePeriodEnd"), 
        row("TransactionAmount"), 
        row("PaymentType"), 
        row("CheckNo")))
    count += 1
Next
```

Comment: That's not what [`String.PadRight()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx) does. You want to use [`String.Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thats also not how Padright works - you are padding the literal "ProcessDate" rather than the value it holds: `row("ProcessDate").ToString().PadRight(6)`

Comment: If it is a DateTime column use it that way to format the result: `Convert.ToDateTime(row("ProcessDate")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Also some dates in that format will be 10 characters long - "12/12/2016" for example.

Comment: how about the others that is not in date format? That is actually in string format? @ChrisF

Answer (score 1):

The `PadRight` method work aligning and adding spaces (by default) to the string.
If the total width is less then the string length it will return a reference to the original string.
So, it will not short your string.
I sugest you take a look at [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

As mentioned by ChrisF in the comments, the Substring solution will solve the problem partially only.

If, for sure, the `row("ProcessDate")` will always give you a valid date, you can just change your format string for `"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}"`.

If it can be a `Nothing`, there are many solutions you can use to solve this problem, I will post one.

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    Dim dt As DateTime
    Dim finalValue As String = If(DateTime.TryParse(row("ProcessDate"), dt), dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Default value")

    swMonetary.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}",
        finalValue, 
        row("SubscriberAccountNumber"), 
        row("PayorName"), 
        row("ParNumber"), 
        row("MemberType"), 
        row("ApplicablePeriodStart"), 
        row("ApplicablePeriodEnd"), 
        row("TransactionAmount"), 
        row("PaymentType"), 
        row("CheckNo")))
    count += 1
Next
```

- This solution will take care if the database returns a Nothing in the date row.
- Also remember to change "dd/MM/yyyy" for the format string that fits your needs.
- And the "Default value" for a default value :), String.Empty maybe.

Comment: The only problem here would be that Substring(0, 9) would truncate dates like "12/12/2016"

Comment: Hi @PauloJunior , how about for others? I am not just focusing on the ProcessDate Table I am also much interested for the other like "PaymentType"

Comment: You can use pretty much the same approach for the others, if it is a date or a decimal, you can try parse, just like the date I show. If it is a string try the Substring method we talked already. This links i will provide can really help you with formating for Standard ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx ) or Custom numeric format strings, there you can find also information on how to format Dates or Enums if you need. If still you need any help on formating other fields, give us more information on what results you really want, maybe examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Dim dt As DateTime
            Dim finalValue As String = If(DateTime.TryParse(row("ProcessDate"), dt), dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Default value")
            Dim SubscriberNumber As String = row("SubscriberAccountNumber")
            Dim PayorName As String = row("PayorName")
            Dim ParNumber As String = row("ParNumber")
            Dim MemberType As String = row("MemberType")
            Dim Start As String = row("ApplicablePeriodStart")
            Dim Ends As String = row("ApplicablePeriodEnd")
            Dim Amount As String = Convert.ToDouble(row("TransactionAmount"))
            Dim PaymentType As String = row("PaymentType")
            Dim CheckNo As String = row("CheckNo")
            swMonetary.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}", finalValue.PadRight(15), SubscriberNumber.PadRight(20), PayorName.PadRight(30), ParNumber.PadRight(20), MemberType.PadRight(20), Start.PadRight(6), Ends.PadRight(6), Amount.PadRight(15), PaymentType.PadRight(10), CheckNo.PadRight(25)))
            count += 1
        Next
```

I found another solution. =)